# How to use javascript libraries to make AJAX calls in Facebook Canvas app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am writing a Facebook canvas app that needs to make some AJAX calls after a user sends app requests to friends. However, every time I load a javascript library to help with the AJAX calls, it causes the Facebook Javascript SDK to stop working.

I'm loading the Javascript SDK just after the  tag as instructed in Facebook documentation.

When users click a button to send a request to a friend, it calls a function like this:

```
function sendrequest() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Play this game!',
        max_recipients: 1,
    }, 
    function(response) {
        var to = response.to;
        var requestid = response.request;
        //here I want to send these to a PHP page
        //via AJAX for processing
    });
}
```

I started with jQuery loaded between `<head>` and `</head>`, but suddenly the `FB.ui` function that sends app requests stopped working. The console says that the `sendrequest()` function is undefined.

[Another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418640/facebook-app-ajax-and-internet-explorer) suggested using the PHPLiveX, which was working for the person who had asked that question. However, loading this javascript creates the exact same problem. If the page loads any javascript library other than just the Facebook javascript SDK, then the SDK stops working.

Any thoughts on what could cause this? I realize I can use XMLHttpRequest but I hoped to use a library to save time on lots of AJAX calls.

Comment: It's not the library making the SDK stop working. I use jQuery in a lot of my facebook apps...

Comment: When I do not load it, the SDK works. When the only change I make is to load jQuery, the SDK does not work. Any input on what that could be?

Comment: where are you loading it? what order are your scripts in your page?

Comment: Thank you for asking and contributing to the conversation, @ahren. Your question prompted me to look over my code and I realized that I was using self-closing script tags, as indicated in my answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered my problem. I included jQuery by typing the code from scratch, and temporarily forgot that [script tags cannot be self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work):

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" />
```

did not work. But

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

works fine.